# Return Functions using prototype's Event.observe

Tags: return, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm trying to migrate from using inline event triggers to using event listeners using Prototype's Event.observe function. There are a few inline commands that I don't know how to handle using the function call.

I want to move from:

```
<form id='formFoo' action='whatever.php' onsubmit="return Foo.verify(this);">
```

To an event call:

```
Event.observe('formFoo', 'submit', Foo.verify);
```

This of course will not work, as I need a return value from the function I call to determine whether the form gets submitted or not.

How do I do this using event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably [`Event.Stop`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/stop) from prototype. This works for me (put this in any script block):

```
Foo = { verify: function(){ return false } };

Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    Event.observe('formFoo', 'submit', function(e){
        if(! Foo.verify($('formFoo'))){
            e.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

It stops every form submission; you will just have to change Foo.verify to do what you wanted.

**Explanation:** When the submit event is triggered, prototype passes the handler a prototype `Event` object representing the event, and the `stop` method on that object prevents the submit. The rest is just setting up the event.

**Minor note:** Among other things, passing *Foo.verify* directly as a handler will cause verify to be called as a function, not a method (*this* will be the global object within the call, rather than Foo). That situation might be okay - if *verify* doesn't use *this*, you're fine. Be aware of the difference, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still allows the form to be submitted before the results of the verify function are returned. This works fine on a button (using click event), but this is a search form, and there is only one input, so if the user hits 'Enter', the form is submitted

Comment: You updated your answer while I was typing my response... the above works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Click the little checkbox if you like it :)